# C++ - gtkmm display both text and image in a ToolButton

Tags: c++, toolbar, gtkmm

I have a toolbar in my Gtkmm application. I am able to add `ToolButton` that have either text with `Gtk::manage(new Gtk::ToolButton("Add"));` or an icon, using : `button->set_icon_name("document-new")`.

I have not found any method that `ToolButton` has to display both the text and the icon. The method available seems to only be available for the `Button` class, which the class `ToolButton` doesn't inherit from.

Using `button->set_label("Add")` afterward also doesn't work. The only thing that is displayed is an icon.

How can I display both text and icon in my `ToolButton` ?

Comment: Did you try using `set_icon_widget()` after `set_icon_name(..)` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an icon to a ToolButton in Gtk 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349642/adding-an-icon-to-a-toolbutton-in-gtk-3)